# how to fill AvFrame pixel by pixel

Tags: c++, video, ffmpeg, libavcodec, libav

i try to encode opengl output to a mp4 file using ffmpeg but when i want to simply fill AvFrame with pixel colors with this code snippet :

```
for (y = 0; y < c->height; y++) {
for (x = 0; x < c->width; x++) {
    int offset = 3 * (x + y * c->width);

    if (x > 2* c->width / 3 && x <c->width )
    {
        frame->data[0][offset + 0] = 0; // B
        frame->data[0][offset + 1] = 0; // G
        frame->data[0][offset + 2] = 255; // R
    } 
    else if(x < 2 * c->width / 3 && x > c->width / 3) {
        frame->data[0][offset + 0] = 0; // B
        frame->data[0][offset + 1] = 255; // G
        frame->data[0][offset + 2] = 0; // R
    }
    else {
        frame->data[0][offset + 0] = 255; // B
        frame->data[0][offset + 1] = 0; // G
        frame->data[0][offset + 2] = 0; // R
    }
}
```

then i have this video output :

[image]

and i had this options for ffmpeg :

**codec: libx264rgb**
& **pix_fmt : AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24**

in fact i expect something like this video output :

[image]

i'm also new in ffmpeg and i realy dont know advanced stuffs about video encoding ,so anybody knows what is problem?

Answer (score 1):

i changed :

```
ret = av_frame_get_buffer(frame, 32);
```

to

```
ret = av_frame_get_buffer(frame, 1);
```

and it fixed.

Comment: This is a workaround to the issue, which has performance implications and might even cause incorrect results. Row size in bytes in the plane can be bigger than required to hold all the pixels; correct way is to account for that. Use `frame->linesize` field to calculate offset in the plane: `offset = 3 * x + y * c->linesize[0]`.

Comment: @Andrey Turkin ,yes your solution also works,thanks!